# Classify 2-by-N data set

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, classification

I have a dataset, say Q, of the following dimension ( data in the columns are independent )

```
Q1                  Q2   
0.676638655462185   0.470588235294118
0.889747899159664   0.976470588235294
0.867478991596639   0.494117647058824
0.886974789915966   0.600000000000000
0.823109243697479   0.435294117647059
0.757226890756303   0.0941176470588235
0.751764705882353   0.235294117647059
0.935294117647059   0.0941176470588235
0.927899159663866   0.576470588235294
0.913109243697479   0.329411764705882
0.888151260504202   0.400000000000000
0.935714285714286   0.305882352941177
0.583781512605042   0.0588235294117647
0.827394957983193   0.141176470588235
0.938823529411765   0.317647058823529
0.941176470588235   0.541176470588235
0.942352941176471   0.164705882352941
```

I want to classify this into the class `p = 0.2 : 0.2 : 1`; where the differences between the classes will be 20%. For the classification of the data, both the values should be considered.

I tried with clustering, but the results of clustering is not convincing. I tried with `NEWPR`, but still could not do any thing.

My original data is composed of `42-8-21` (a total of 71) attributes for 17 instances. I also tried from that side. For the `NEWPR`, I used some determinative attributes - one or two (out of that 71) - as the target.  Even I tried with splitting the database in to some percentile.  Since *my data does not have 1/0*, no results were out.

The classification worked well when I took a 60% bench mark and simple logic of (`Q1 > 0.60 & Q2 > 0.60`) sort of logic. The results I got for classifications were pretty good. In that case serialization of the data were a problem and I did that manually. However, that is not convincing to me, because more data need to be classified based on the model.

I am not sure if (`0< Q1 < 0.20 & 0 < Q2 < 0.2`) sort of logic can be used in Matlab?

Else, can I use any sort of commonly used grading system for this classification?

Please help me in finding a customized solution for this problem.

Comment: _"... but the results of clustering is not convincing"_. Why? Can you show them (and the code that produces them)?

Comment: those are the normal Matlab clustering codes for kmeans:
[ idx, c ] = kmeans( Q', 6, 'distance', 'cityblock', 'replicates', 500 );

Comment: I'm not familiar with the class definition of `p = 0.2 : 0.2 : 1` can you clarify what this means?

Comment: sorry, that was the code I wrote for the class with spacing 20% from each other: 20%, 40%, 60%, 80%, 100%.  Hope now it is clear to you @slayton

Answer (score 0):

`(0< Q1 < 0.20 & 0 < Q2 < 0.2)` will be interpreted as `((0<Q1)<.2)&(0<Q2)<.2)` which will only be true for Q1 and Q2 less than or equal to 0.
Use `((0<Q1)&(Q1<0.2)&(0<Q2)&(Q2<0.2))`